# Starting/Stopping Services on a remote PC

Tags: windows, permissions, service

I need to be able to remotely start and stop services on another windows machine  in the domain.

If I open up the "Service Manager" I can connect to the remote machine and view all its services however when I try to start or stop a service I get access denied.

Can anyone let me know what the minimum permissions are that a user needs to be able to start/stop services on another machine?

The account I'm currently trying to do this under has remote admin rights on the remote PC but still fails.

Thanks

Comment: Does this happen with all services, or just particular ones? Is this an admin on the remote machine, or a domain admin? If you're logged into that machine at the console as the user you're trying to use remotely can the user start/stop services from there?

Comment: Also, what is the OS on the remote machine?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK Rebooting the remote PC seemed to fix the issue. No idea why, or even if its fixed permanently but just thought I'd let you know the problem seems to have gone away. I hate it when that happens for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some policy to deny or permit the service control remotely (Local security policy).

Similar questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269/remotely-starting-and-stopping-a-service-on-a-w2008-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it from a Linux box,  [Restart Windows Services from Your Linux PC @ Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5575671/restart-windows-services-from-your-linux-pc) is a great article!

Answer (score 0):

Try using psservice.exe from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx
It has command line options -U and -P to use a different username & password.  It mentions: *Use the username and password to log into the remote computer in cases where your account does not have permissions to perform the action you specify.*